# Bootstrap 3 two column thumbnail layout not working. Conflict with Jquery Isotope? Issue with Chrome?

Tags: jquery, thumbnails, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

**Edit: Seems to be an issue in Chrome, but not Safari. Not sure if that helps narrow it down…**

I'm having a problem that for the life of me, I can't figure out. I am trying to use Twitter Bootstrap 3's .thumbnail class to create a two column layout (nested inside another div). Everything seems to work fine until I apply Jquery Isotope's masonry feature on the .thumbnail divs—two thumbnail divs no longer fit, and instead, there is just one image per row (taking up the correct amount of space in the "left" column. I really can't figure what it is that's causing it, but if I remove the Isotope classes from the html everything works fine. I'm guessing there might be some sort of padding issue or something because the image width doesn't seem to change, but I can't find where it's happening. I have even deactivated the Isotope CSS and it still happens. Also, if I make the thumbnail divs slightly narrower (e.g. col-sm-5 instead of col-sm-6) the rows no longer break. Here is an example of a page with it happening:

http://goo.gl/2gaUSQ

To confuse things even more, I tried to recreate the problem in a JSfiddle but everything seems to work fine :(

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/452

Also, I'm currently working on another site where I did this exact same thing, and after a lot of tinkering, it works fine (it's only two column in really small screens, but it works at all sizes):

http://goo.gl/Dzbu1C

If anyone could offer any help, or point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it! Here is a bit of my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:red;">
    <div class="row iso" style="background-color:yellow;">
      <?php if($page->hasImages()): ?> 
        <?php foreach($page->images() 
                           ->not('thumb.jpg') 
                           ->not('thumb.gif') 
                           as $image): ?>   
        <div class="item col-xs-6">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="<?php echo $image->url() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image->url() ?>" width="<?php echo $image->width(); ?>" height="<?php echo $image->height(); ?>"></a>
        </div><!--item-->
        <?php endforeach ?>
      <?php endif ?>        
    </div><!--row-->
</div><!--col-sm-6-->
```

Here is the code for Istope (placed at the end, just before the  tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // jQuery - Wait until images (and other resources) are loaded
$(window).load(function(){
        // All images, css style sheets and external resources are loaded
$('.iso').isotope({
  // options
  itemSelector : '.item',
  layoutMode : 'masonry'
})   
});</script>
```

Thank you so much!!!!

**EDIT: I can't believe I didn't notice this until now, but everything seems to work with Safari. I have been testing on Chrome and it's not working. So maybe that can provide a clue??**

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem, i dont know why this is happening too. But i got around this if i change the "@grid-gutter-width" in the bootstrap 3 customization to another value, try 29px instead of 30px.

hope someone could real help.